# Identify Type of Histogram from Array

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, histogram

How to identify flatter or wider histogram from the Histogram Array.

This is how I calculate the data.

```
public typealias HistogramData = (red: [vImagePixelCount], blue: [vImagePixelCount], green: [vImagePixelCount], alpha: [vImagePixelCount])

extension UIImage {
    public func getHistogramValues() -> HistogramData {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return (red: [], green: [], blue: [], alpha: [])
        }

        var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 32,
            colorSpace: nil,
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(
                rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue),
            version: 0,
            decode: nil,
            renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)

        var inBuffer: vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer()

        vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(
            &inBuffer,
            &format,
            nil,
            cgImage,
            UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

        let red = Array<vImagePixelCount>(repeatElement(0, count: 256))
        let green = Array<vImagePixelCount>(repeatElement(0, count: 256))
        let blue = Array<vImagePixelCount>(repeatElement(0, count: 256))
        let alpha = Array<vImagePixelCount>(repeatElement(0, count: 256))

        let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?>.allocate(capacity: 4)
        histogram[0] = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: red)
        histogram[1] = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: green)
        histogram[2] = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: blue)
        histogram[3] = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha)

        vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

        free(inBuffer.data)

        return (red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }

    /// Turns a RGB - Image into a Grayscale (⬛️⬜️) - Image
    public var asGrayScaleImage: UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
        filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: "inputImage")

        let context = CIContext()
        let result = context.createCGImage((filter?.outputImage)!, from: filter!.outputImage!.extent)
        return UIImage(cgImage: result!)
    }
}
```

Output:

> (red: [62322, 163353, 66666, 10948, 2812, 788, 233, 45, 20, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], blue: [62322, 163353, 66666, 10948, 2812, 788, 233, 45, 20, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], green: [62322, 163353, 66666, 10948, 2812, 788, 233, 45, 20, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], alpha: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 307200])

I need to verify whether the image is Good image or not. check below for reference
[image]

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/602/?time=2236

Comment: What are you looking for? How do you define a "flatter" histogram and a "wider" histogram? Also, please tag with a programming language.

Comment: The image you added to the question talks about "narrow histogram", but you're asking to distinguish a "flatter" from a "wider" histogram. What that image means, I think, by "narrow" is that a lot of the histogram bins are 0. Did you try to count the number of 0 bins in the histogram?

Comment: But approx how many 0s are considered narrow? I have shared image in which right example is of Narrow histogram which I want eliminate. If image is narrow then I have to reject that.

Comment: Take a couple of images that you consider bad, and a couple that you consider good. Compute their histograms and count the number of 0 bins. Find a threshold that distinguishes images from the two sets. I don't think there's a universal threshold here, it's up to you to define that.